Meta Graph API Explorer - Generate token fails
I'm working on an app using the Threads API from meta.
I have created the application successfully on the developer console, and am trying to test access using the Graph API Explorer. I've selected "threads.net" from the endpoint dropdown, and the application I created from the "Meta app" dropdown, but when I try to generate an access token, the approval window appears, I click continue, and then it just says "URL Blocked"
Is there something I'm missing?

This seems to have been resolved, the API Explorer generates a token correctly now
